# Build test project automatically when selecting Run All in Test Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio Community Edition 2013. When I select Run All in the Test Explorer, the latest changes I have done to the test code will not be included. I have to remember to right-click on my tests project and choose Build each time, and it is annoying.

How can I fix so that the build is always done automatically, like it is when running an ordinary project?

Comment: did you look through the settings? maybe there is a setting of this sort

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find anything. Though the settings aren't especially easy to search through. It is hard to google this topic too, because it turns up a lot of questions about how to run tests when building, but I want it the other way around.

Comment: This is very weird... I found your question because I want the opposite: whenever I try to run all tests, VS will _always_ compile everything again, which in our case is very slow. I wonder how you got that behavior to begin with (or how we got ours, now I'm not sure what the default is anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: for some reason the active solution configuration in the Configuration Manager (reached by right-clicking the solution in the Solution explorer) was set to not build all projects. I don't know how this came to be, but now it works at least.